# Somehow I can't create a window anymore without changing the code

Tags: winapi, x86, masm

I try to write pong in assembly to get a better understanding of what actually happens in my pc

I have disabled my av which would flag it as harmful and have restarted my pc with av disabled and the code worked before and I didn't change anything. It could by some stupid oversight but it as a normally high level programmer it is really weird that the code just stopped working after restarting my pc. I don't get any concerning errors.

I get

> hello.asm(51) : warning A6001: no return from procedure

this as an error but I could ignore it before and it compiles and like I said it worked before.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include C:\MASM32\include\masm32rt.inc
includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib

.data
    txClass db "MyWinClass", 0
    wcx     WNDCLASSEX <WNDCLASSEX, CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW, WndProc, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, COLOR_BTNFACE+1, 0, txClass, 4>
    rect    RECT <20, 0, 40, 100> ; Rectangle to hold the client area dimensions
    ball    RECT <200, 200, 210,210> ; Rectangle to hold the client area dimensions
    ballMX  DWORD 5
    ballMY  DWORD 5
.data? ; uninitialised data - use for handles etc
    hMenu   dd ?
    ps PAINTSTRUCT<?>
    dwStartTime DWORD ?
    dwElapsedTime DWORD ?
    hWnd2  DWORD ?
.code
WinMain proc uses ebx
    LOCAL msg:MSG

    
    
    mov ebx, offset wcx
    wc equ [ebx.WNDCLASSEX]
    mov wc.hInstance, rv(GetModuleHandle, 0)
    mov wc.hIcon, rv(LoadIcon, NULL, IDI_APPLICATION)
    mov wc.hIconSm, eax

    invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc
    invoke CreateWindowEx, NULL, wc.lpszClassName, chr$("Pong"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW or WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL

    mov hWnd2, eax
    invoke SetTimer, hWnd2, 1, 8, NULL

    .While 1
        invoke GetMessage, ADDR msg, NULL, 0, 0
        .Break .if !eax
        invoke TranslateMessage, ADDR msg
        invoke DispatchMessage, ADDR msg
    .Endw
    
    exit msg.wParam
WinMain endp

WndProc proc uses esi edi ebx hWnd, uMsg, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
    LOCAL hdc: HDC

    
    SWITCH uMsg

    CASE WM_CREATE
    ret
    CASE WM_KEYDOWN
        mov eax, wParam
        SWITCH eax
        CASE VK_S
            add dword ptr [rect.top], 5
            add dword ptr [rect.bottom], 5
        CASE VK_W
            sub dword ptr [rect.top], 5
            sub dword ptr [rect.bottom], 5
            ret
    ret
    ENDSW
    invoke InvalidateRect, hWnd, NULL, TRUE ; Force the window to repaint
    ret 

    CASE WM_TIMER
        push ebx
        mov eax, ball.bottom
        mov ebx, ps.rcPaint.bottom
        cmp eax,ebx
        jb cont
        neg  ballMY
    cont:
        mov eax,ballMY
        add ball.top, eax     
        add ball.bottom, eax
        
        xor ebx, ebx
        
        mov eax, ball.right
        mov ebx, ps.rcPaint.right
        cmp eax,ebx
        jb cont2
        neg  ballMX
    cont2:
        mov eax,ballMX
        add ball.left, eax     
        add ball.right, eax    
        
        pop ebx
        
        
        
        
        invoke InvalidateRect, hWnd, NULL, TRUE  ; Request a repaint

    CASE WM_PAINT
    
        invoke BeginPaint, hWnd, ADDR ps ; Start painting the window
        mov hdc, eax                   ; Store the device context handle
        invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0000000
        invoke FillRect, hdc, ADDR ps.rcPaint, eax


        invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0FFFFFFh
        invoke FillRect, hdc, ADDR rect, eax
        
        
        invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0FFFFFFh
        invoke FillRect, hdc, ADDR ball, eax

        invoke EndPaint, hWnd, ADDR ps   ; End painting
        ret

    CASE WM_DESTROY
        invoke PostQuitMessage, NULL

    ENDSW
    invoke DefWindowProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
    ret
WndProc endp

end WinMain
```

Comment: You don't seem to be setting a return value from your WndProc. E.g. `WM_CREATE` requires you to return 0 to continue the creation of the window.  You also have a resource leak in your `WM_PAINT` handler.

Comment: I have added 
        invoke DeleteObject, hBlackBrush
        invoke DeleteObject, hWhiteBrush
        invoke DeleteObject, hWhiteBrush2
to avoid the  resource leak
and added a return value to WM_CREATE
    CASE WM_CREATE
        mov eax, 0  
        ret
also added a default case
 DEFAULT ; Handle unhandled message cases
        invoke DefWindowProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
        mov eax, 0
        ret 
but it still doesn't create a window, but it gets compiled and if I run it, it doesn't crash

Comment: In the default case, when you invoke `DefWindowProc` you should return the value returned by that function, so it should follow a `ret` without the `mov eax, 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RegisterClassEx` was failing

```
invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc
```

Replaced the original code with new code that fills the WNDCLASSEX structure with required variables.

Running the code produces this window

[image: pong]

**pong.asm**

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include C:\MASM32\include\masm32rt.inc
includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib

.data
    txClass db "MyWinClass", 0
    rect    RECT <20, 0, 40, 100> ; Rectangle to hold the client area dimensions
    ball    RECT <200, 200, 210,210> ; Rectangle to hold the client area dimensions
    ballMX  DWORD 5
    ballMY  DWORD 5
.data? ; uninitialised data - use for handles etc
    hMenu   dd ?
    ps PAINTSTRUCT<?>
    dwStartTime DWORD ?
    dwElapsedTime DWORD ?
    hWnd2  DWORD ?


.code
WinMain proc hInst     :DWORD,
             hPrevInst :DWORD,
             CmdLine   :DWORD,
             CmdShow   :DWORD   
    
        ;====================
        ; Put LOCALs on stack
        ;====================

        LOCAL wc   :WNDCLASSEX
        LOCAL msg  :MSG

        LOCAL Wwd  :DWORD
        LOCAL Wht  :DWORD
        LOCAL Wtx  :DWORD
        LOCAL Wty  :DWORD

        ;==================================================
        ; Fill WNDCLASSEX structure with required variables
        ;==================================================

        mov wc.cbSize,         sizeof WNDCLASSEX
        mov wc.style,          CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW \
                               or CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW
        mov wc.lpfnWndProc,    offset WndProc
        mov wc.cbClsExtra,     NULL
        mov wc.cbWndExtra,     NULL
        m2m wc.hInstance,      hInst   ;<< NOTE: macro not mnemonic
        mov wc.hbrBackground,  COLOR_BTNFACE+1
        mov wc.lpszMenuName,   NULL
        mov wc.lpszClassName,  offset txClass
        invoke LoadIcon,hInst,500    ; icon ID
        mov wc.hIcon,          eax
        invoke LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW
        mov wc.hCursor,        eax
        mov wc.hIconSm,        0

        invoke RegisterClassEx, ADDR wc
        test eax, eax
        jnz regOk

        invoke MessageBox,0,SADD("RegistrationFailed"),
                            SADD("Oops"),
                            MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION
        jmp done
                                 
regOk:
    invoke CreateWindowEx, NULL, wc.lpszClassName, chr$("Pong"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW or WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL

    mov hWnd2, eax
    invoke ShowWindow,hWnd2,SW_SHOWNORMAL
    invoke UpdateWindow,hWnd2

    invoke SetTimer, hWnd2, 1, 8, NULL

    .While 1
        invoke GetMessage, ADDR msg, NULL, 0, 0
        .Break .if !eax
        invoke TranslateMessage, ADDR msg
        invoke DispatchMessage, ADDR msg
    .Endw

done:
    exit msg.wParam
WinMain endp

WndProc proc uses esi edi ebx hWnd, uMsg, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
    LOCAL hdc: HDC

    
    SWITCH uMsg

    CASE WM_CREATE
    ret
    CASE WM_KEYDOWN
        mov eax, wParam
        SWITCH eax
        CASE VK_S
            add dword ptr [rect.top], 5
            add dword ptr [rect.bottom], 5
        CASE VK_W
            sub dword ptr [rect.top], 5
            sub dword ptr [rect.bottom], 5
            ret
    ret
    ENDSW
    invoke InvalidateRect, hWnd, NULL, TRUE ; Force the window to repaint
    ret 

    CASE WM_TIMER
        push ebx
        mov eax, ball.bottom
        mov ebx, ps.rcPaint.bottom
        cmp eax,ebx
        jb cont
        neg  ballMY
    cont:
        mov eax,ballMY
        add ball.top, eax     
        add ball.bottom, eax
        
        xor ebx, ebx
        
        mov eax, ball.right
        mov ebx, ps.rcPaint.right
        cmp eax,ebx
        jb cont2
        neg  ballMX
    cont2:
        mov eax,ballMX
        add ball.left, eax     
        add ball.right, eax    
        
        pop ebx
        
        
        
        
        invoke InvalidateRect, hWnd, NULL, TRUE  ; Request a repaint

    CASE WM_PAINT
    
        invoke BeginPaint, hWnd, ADDR ps ; Start painting the window
        mov hdc, eax                   ; Store the device context handle
        invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0000000
        invoke FillRect, hdc, ADDR ps.rcPaint, eax


        invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0FFFFFFh
        invoke FillRect, hdc, ADDR rect, eax
        
        
        invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0FFFFFFh
        invoke FillRect, hdc, ADDR ball, eax

        invoke EndPaint, hWnd, ADDR ps   ; End painting
        ret

    CASE WM_DESTROY
        invoke PostQuitMessage, NULL

    ENDSW
    invoke DefWindowProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
    ret
WndProc endp

end WinMain
```

There are lots of examples in `C:\masm32\tools` and `C:\masm32\examples` which uses this code to register the windows class correctly

```
RegisterWinClass proc lpWndProc:DWORD, lpClassName:DWORD,
                      Icon:DWORD, Cursor:DWORD, bColor:DWORD

    LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX

    mov wc.cbSize,         sizeof WNDCLASSEX
    mov wc.style,          CS_BYTEALIGNCLIENT or \
                           CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW
    m2m wc.lpfnWndProc,    lpWndProc
    mov wc.cbClsExtra,     NULL
    mov wc.cbWndExtra,     NULL
    m2m wc.hInstance,      hInstance
    m2m wc.hbrBackground,  bColor
    mov wc.lpszMenuName,   NULL
    m2m wc.lpszClassName,  lpClassName
    m2m wc.hIcon,          Icon
    m2m wc.hCursor,        Cursor
    m2m wc.hIconSm,        Icon

    invoke RegisterClassEx, ADDR wc

    ret

RegisterWinClass endp
```

Comment: I am really thankful for this response, but it still doesn't show any window for some reason. I have no clue why it doesn't show anything, do you know why the code works on your machine but mine doesn't show any windows?

Comment: Updated the code...the `invoke RegisterClassEx, addr wc` was failing. Probably should add error checks around more window function calls.

Comment: but I exactly copied the code and it worked before I restarted my pc

Comment: Most likely we both got lucky with the window showing up randomly. Probably some quirky internal state of the program. Does the new code work now? If so, you can narrow it down to find why it's failing. Thanks.

Comment: @Jannis: Buggy programs that leave some things uninitialized are *not* guaranteed to break, they might happen to work depending on random state like exactly what ends up in a certain piece of stack memory.  In assembly, it's very easy to make mistakes like leaving something uninitialized, unlike in C.  So the fact that it was working before does *not* prove that it was correct and future-proof.  Yes, rebooting could be enough to re-randomize an address or environment size or something that was making your program happen to work.