# why is no window showing?

Tags: windows, assembly, winapi, x86, masm

Im trying to open a window using the windows api in x86 masm. The following code executes with code 0 and I can't figure out why no window is appearing.

```
.code
WindowProc proc wHWND:DWORD, uMsg:DWORD, wParam:DWORD, lParam:DWORD
    LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEXA

    .if uMsg == 1
        mov eax, lParam
        mov [wHWND], eax
    .elseif uMsg == 2
        invoke ExitProcess, 0
    .else
        invoke DefWindowProcA, wHWND, uMsg, wParam, lParam
        ret
    .endif
    
    xor eax, eax
    ret
WindowProc endp

wWinMain proc hInstance:DWORD, hPrevInstance:DWORD, pCmdLine:DWORD, nCmdShow:DWORD
    LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEXA

mov dword ptr [wc.cbSize], 48
    mov eax, 2
    or eax, 1
    mov dword ptr [wc.style], eax
    mov dword ptr [wc.lpfnWndProc], OFFSET WindowProc
    mov dword ptr [wc.cbClsExtra], 0
    mov dword ptr [wc.cbWndExtra], 0
    mov eax, dword ptr [hInstance]
    mov dword ptr [wc.hInstance], eax
    mov dword ptr [wc.hbrBackground], 5
    mov dword ptr [wc.lpszClassName], OFFSET className
    lea eax, [wc]
    invoke RegisterClassExA, eax
    mov eax, 0
    or eax, 12582912
    or eax, 524288
    or eax, 262144
    or eax, 131072
    or eax, 65536
    invoke CreateWindowExA, 0, OFFSET className, OFFSET WindowName, eax, 360, 140, 362, 382, 0, 0, hInstance, 0
    mov dword ptr [windowHWND], eax
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
wWinMain endp
    end wWinMain
```

this is just the .code portion of the asm. wWinMain is the entry point alot of the numbers are windows enums and defines i.e. 12582912,524288,262144,131072,65536

Comment: Where's your message loop?

Comment: shouldnt a blank window still show for a moment the disappear

Comment: I don't believe so. You need something to dispatch wm_Paint, and so on.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window msdn shows this way using ShowWindow function i tried with that but still nothing

Comment: your process is exit in any case. nothing must be shown

Comment: added the message loop but still no window

Comment: It looks like you call ExitProcess immediately after CreateWindow.

Comment: Your call to `CreateWindowExA` doesn't specify the `WS_VISIBLE` window style, thus the window is created initially hidden. You will have to set the `WS_VISIBLE` flag, or call `ShowWindow` to toggle the visibility bit.

Comment: I think You should place after `.code` some instructions what to do because You have only procedures definitions. `invoke GetModuleHandle,0`,`mov hInstance,eax`, `invoke WinMain,hInstance,0,0,10`, `invoke ExitProcess,eax`

Answer (score 1):

Look through the whole document, [Module 1. Your First Windows Program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program).

In the view of Windows desktop programming, your application needs [a message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/window-messages#the-message-loop) as @500-InternalServerError pointed. At the rest, as [@IInspectable said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76891324/why-is-no-window-showing#comment135552736_76891324),

> Your call to CreateWindowExA doesn't specify the WS_VISIBLE window
> style, thus the window is created initially hidden. You will have to
> set the WS_VISIBLE flag, or call ShowWindow to toggle the visibility
> bit.

Comment: Very similar issue asked here about a window not showing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76807674/somehow-i-cant-create-a-window-anymore-without-changing-the-code

Comment: @vengy The issues are vastly different, evidenced by vastly different solutions.